# How to use slice to get data between a given range

Tags: javascript, json

i have a JSON array in this form

```
var data = [{"transDate":new Date("01/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("02/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("03/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("04/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("05/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("06/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("07/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("08/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("09/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("10/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("11/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("12/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("13/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("14/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("15/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("16/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("17/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("18/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("19/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("20/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("21/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("22/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("23/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("24/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("25/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("26/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("27/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("28/01/2018"),"temperature":35}
    ];
```

now i have a date range in this form

```
01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018
```

i want to get all the data from the json array between this data range.So how do i do this using slice function ?

Comment: Using _just_ slice? I don't see that being possible. You would have to use `filter()` or some other way.

Comment: You need to loop it to get the desired output.

Comment: You will  get invalid date with `new Date("DD/MM/YYYY")` format

Comment: @Jhecht how to do it using filter

Comment: It assumingm you have your start date and end date in variables `start` and `end`, `var filtered = data.filtered( function(cum, cur){ if( cur>= start && cur <= end) cum.push(cur); return cur} , [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` and compare your dates with the `startDate` and `endDate` values. Using `splice` does not really allow you to achieve the desired result.

```js
var data = [{"transDate":new Date("01/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("02/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("01/10/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("04/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("05/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("06/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("07/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("08/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("09/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("10/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("11/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("12/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("13/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("14/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("15/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("16/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("17/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("18/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("19/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("20/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("21/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("22/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("23/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("24/01/2018"),"temperature":35},
      {"transDate":new Date("25/01/2018"),"temperature":95},
      {"transDate":new Date("26/01/2018"),"temperature":62},
      {"transDate":new Date("27/01/2018"),"temperature":51},
      {"transDate":new Date("28/01/2018"),"temperature":35}
    ];

var startDate = '01/01/2018';
var endDate = '01/15/2018';

var res = data.filter(dateObj => new Date(startDate) <dateObj.transDate && dateObj.transDate<new Date(endDate));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `({ transDate }) => new Date(startDate) < transDate && transDate< new Date(endDate)` is more readable, though you might want to initialize `startDate` and `endDate` _before_ `filter()` so you're not re-initializing them from the strings for every element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do i do this using slice function ?

For `slice` to work, you need indexes of **start index** and **end index**. Use `findIndex` for the same (***Assuming that data is sorted by date in ascending order***)

```
var startDate = "01/01/2018";
var endDate = "01/15/2018";
var fnIsGreaterOrEqual = (dateObj, dateStr) => {}; //logic for date comparison
var startIndex = data.findIndex( s => fnIsGreaterOrEqual(s.transDate, startDate) );
var endIndex = data.findIndex( s => fnIsGreaterOrEqual(s.transDate, endDate) );
var output = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
```

However, **recommended solution** would be to use `filter` itself

```
var fnToDateObj = (dateStr) => {}; //logic for date conversion
var startDate = fnToDateObj("01/01/2018");
var endDate = fnToDateObj("15/01/2018");
var output = data.filter( s => s.transDate >= startDate && s.transDate <= endDate );
```